# How to check if two addresses are the same?

Tags: c++, operators, memory-address

If given a function `operator=`, how can I check if two memory addresses are the same? I believe the following is correct, but it uses the `==` operator rather than the one defined. How would I do this with the `=` operator?

```
if(&this == &rhs)
    return true;
```

Comment: `operator=` is an _assignment_ operator, not comparison.

Comment: `if(&this == &rhs)` You probably want to use `if(this == &rhs)` but narrowed the context of your question too much.

Comment: _"How would I do this with the = operator?"_ Huh? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A common implementation of `operator=` is to test for object equality before assigning members.  This is often performed by `if (this != &other)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the right address.  `this` is already a pointer to your object.  And it appears you are trying to implement the common pattern:

```
Foo & Foo::operator=( const Foo & rhs )
{
    if( this == &rhs )
    {
        // :::
    }

    // :::
}
```

Above, the type of `this` is `Foo*`, and `&rhs` is `Foo const *`, making them comparable.

---

*[Edit: added relevant parts from standard, taken from C++14 draft standard]*

From section 5.3.1 **[expr.unary.op]** :

> 3. The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*.  ...

From section 9.3.2 **[class.this]** :

> 1. In the body of a non-static member function, the keyword **this** is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.

Since `this` is neither an lvalue nor a *qualified-id*, you cannot take its address and your compiler should report an error if you try.